# Qual o problema para rodar o app react-native?

Tags: java, react, react-native

Olá, estou tentando rodar o meu app react native através do comando

> sudo react-native run-android

Mas sempre me retorna a seguinte mensagem de erro:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine java version from '11'.
```

Já tentei fazer de tudo

1- Testei a versão do meu java

> java -version

```
openjdk version "11" 2018-09-25
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11+24-Ubuntu-118.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11+24-Ubuntu-118.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

2- Setei o JAVA_HOME, tanto em /etc/enviroment quanto em ~/.bashrc

> echo $JAVA_HOME

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
```

Realmente eu não sei mais o que fazer, pois aparentemente todo o ambiente está preparado para funcionar corretamente.

Comment: Só aparece esse erro ? Ou você só pegou uma parte ? Se possível [edite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/340764/edit) a pergunta e coloque o log completo. Aparentemente esse erro está relacionado ao *Gradle*.

Comment: 1º Teu android studio tá funcionando? Se sim tenta ver essas variáveis https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started#3-configure-the-android-home-environment-variable

Comment: Olá, sim...
Só aparece esse erro, o log completo são umas dicas que não me ajudaram kkk

Answer (score 0):

Boa! então, você pode atualizar o gradle para ver se fica compatível com o OpenJDK 11

Mas eu recomendo usar o oracle jdk 8 :

1 - Remova o seu open JDK 11 (se for baseado em debian: apt purgue --remove openJDK*

2 - baixe o Oracle JDK da SUN : 
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/pt/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

3 - Descompacte com : tar -zxvf

4 - Adicione no seu PATH:
vim ~/.bashrc
export export JAVA_HOME="/local/do/JDK/jdk1.8.0_181"
export CLASSPATH="$JAVA_HOME/lib":$CLASSPATH
export PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin":$PATH
export MANPATH="$JAVA_HOME/man":$MANPATH

E depois de editar : source ~/.bashrc

5 - Alguns casos o java da erro , consultando java -version
Basta seguir esta dica :
https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/topico/Java/O-java-apresenta-um-erro-Preciso-de-ajuda

Depois disso o java estará na versão 8 , e recomendada para o uso .